# jquery tabs: active tab content not showing onload

Tags: jquery, tabs

i am using jquery tab script i saw somewhere. the problem is that the content on default active tab is not showing when page is loaded. When i click on any other tab, the content relative to the active clicked tab shows up, but not onload. i even tried using `$(window).load(function()` instead of `$(document).ready(function()`, but no effect.

here is the jquery code:

```
// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                    // which tab is active and it's associated content
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

                    // Hide the remaining content
                    $links.not($active).each(function () {
                        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                    });

                    // Bind the click event handler
                    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                        // Make the old tab inactive.
                        $active.removeClass('active');
                        $content.hide();

                        // Update the variables with the new link and content
                        $active = $(this);
                        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                        // Make the tab active.
                        $active.addClass('active');
                        $content.show();

                        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5UpJ/ .Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger a manual click event for the `ul.tabs a.active` element once the tab events are attached.

Like

```
$('ul.tabs').find('a.active').click();
```

Try

```
// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }).find('a.active').click();
    //see here the click event is triggered here
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6e56c/)

Comment: .find('a.active').click();  - is this what you added?